# LDA Mallet CalledProcessError

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, lda, mallet

I am trying to implement the following code:

```
import os
os.environ.update({'MALLET_HOME':r'c:/mallet-2.0.8/'})

mallet_path = 'C:\\mallet-2.0.8\\bin\\mallet'
ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=bow, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\mallet-2.0.8\bin\mallet import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Temp\98094d_corpus.txt --output C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Temp\98094d_corpus.mallet' returned non-zero exit status 1.

I previously was able to execute this code on my laptop with the same directories yet it does not execute on my PC (where I am currently running python).

Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar error.  Double check that you have java installed and that the file path is calling java.  I had to edit my mallet.bat file found in the mallet folder C:\mallet\mallet-2.0.8\bin like this:

```html
@echo off

rem This batch file serves as a wrapper for several
rem  MALLET command line tools.

if not "%MALLET_HOME%" == "" goto gotMalletHome

echo MALLET requires an environment variable MALLET_HOME.
goto :eof

:gotMalletHome

set MALLET_CLASSPATH=C:\mallet\mallet-2.0.8\class;C:\mallet\mallet-2.0.8\lib\mallet-deps.jar
set MALLET_MEMORY=1G
set MALLET_ENCODING=UTF-8

set CMD=%1
shift

set CLASS=
if "%CMD%"=="import-dir" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="import-file" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Csv2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="import-svmlight" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.SvmLight2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="info" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Info
if "%CMD%"=="train-classifier" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Classify
if "%CMD%"=="classify-dir" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Classify
if "%CMD%"=="classify-file" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Csv2Classify
if "%CMD%"=="classify-svmlight" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.SvmLight2Classify
if "%CMD%"=="train-topics" set CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.TopicTrainer
if "%CMD%"=="infer-topics" set CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.InferTopics
if "%CMD%"=="evaluate-topics" set CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.EvaluateTopics
if "%CMD%"=="prune" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="split" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="bulk-load" set CLASS=cc.mallet.util.BulkLoader
if "%CMD%"=="run" set CLASS=%1 & shift

if not "%CLASS%" == "" goto gotClass

echo Mallet 2.0 commands: 
echo   import-dir        load the contents of a directory into mallet instances (one per file)
echo   import-file       load a single file into mallet instances (one per line)
echo   import-svmlight   load a single SVMLight format data file into mallet instances (one per line)
echo   info              get information about Mallet instances
echo   train-classifier  train a classifier from Mallet data files
echo   classify-dir      classify data from a single file with a saved classifier
echo   classify-file     classify the contents of a directory with a saved classifier
echo   classify-svmlight classify data from a single file in SVMLight format
echo   train-topics      train a topic model from Mallet data files
echo   infer-topics      use a trained topic model to infer topics for new documents
echo   evaluate-topics   estimate the probability of new documents given a trained model
echo   prune             remove features based on frequency or information gain
echo   split             divide data into testing, training, and validation portions
echo   bulk-load         for big input files, efficiently prune vocabulary and import docs
echo Include --help with any option for more information


goto :eof

:gotClass

set MALLET_ARGS=

:getArg

if "%1"=="" goto run
set MALLET_ARGS=%MALLET_ARGS% %1
shift
goto getArg

:run

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin\java" -ea -Dfile.encoding=%MALLET_ENCODING% -classpath %MALLET_CLASSPATH% %CLASS% %MALLET_ARGS%

:eof
```

Then change your file path to reflect this change:

```html
mallet_path = 'C:/mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet.bat'
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: this helped me a lot, be sure to install java jdk and give path to it in .bat file