# Topic modeling in LdaMallet

Tags: gensim, lda, topic-modeling, mallet

I wrote the following code, 
But the following error shows, 
Please guide me.

```
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet
import os
os.environ.update({'MALLET_HOME':r'C:/mallet'})
mallet_path = 'C:/mallet/bin/mallet'

ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=id2word)
```

**Error:**

> Command 'C:/mallet/bin/mallet import-file --preserve-case
>   --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input C:\Users\MHRADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\316a7f_corpus.txt --output
>   C:\Users\MHRADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\316a7f_corpus.mallet' returned
>   non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: Try: `mallet_path = 'C:/mallet/bin/mallet.bat'` as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363181/saved-gensim-ldamallet-model-not-working-in-different-console

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845345/lda-mallet-calledprocesserror